# What is Control.IsHandleCreated needed for?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I'm examining the source of the built-in .net control for TabControl, and I see that it references this property before deciding whether to Add or Insert a TabPage to the collection.

```
if (this.owner.IsHandleCreated)
{
    this.owner.AddTabPage(tabPage, tabPage.GetTCITEM());
}
else
{
    this.owner.Insert(this.owner.TabCount, tabPage);
}
```

Both functions ultimately accomplish the same goal - they add the TabPage to the end of the internal "TabPages" collection... but I just don't see why it should matter which function you use.

`this` refers to the `ControlCollection` that overrides the built-in `Control.ControlCollection`. `owner` is the TabControl that is making use of the `ControlCollection`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TabControl's `AddTabPage` method (the one that is called when the handle is created) calls the `AddNativeTabPage` method. That in turn calls `SendMessage` and `PostMessage` (effectively, `Control.Invoke` and `Control.BeginInvoke`) to add the tab page.  These methods marshal the addition of the tab page to the UI thread, so that the control is internally obeying [the rule that you shouldn't interact with UI controls from a background thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649143.aspx#scag-ch06_topic4).

This actually means that if the handle has been created, `AddTabPage` is safe to call from non-UI threads (very unusual for a UI control!).  Unfortunately, this also means that the `AddTabPage` method would block if the TabControl didn't yet have a handle, because there would be no UI thread pumping messages, and so it shouldn't be called unless the handle was created.

For the curious, this is in the `TabControl.ControlsCollection` class, in the `Add` method.